# Return the content from textarea with element inside

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a script that would extract me everything within a defined element. In this exemple it's the `<u>` element.

**HTML**

```
<textarea cols="75" rows="25" id="textShit"><u>sd</u></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
    <div id="res"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click',function(){
        $('textarea:contains("u")').each(function() {
            //$('#res').html($(this).val()+'<br>');
            alert($(this).val());
        })
    });
});
```

I would like when I hit submit, in the `<div class="res">`  it returns what's inside every `<u>`.

How to achieve this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/warface/Ewve8/

Comment: Seeing as textareas may contain only text content, I have no idea what you're trying to do. Are you trying to parse the textarea's value or what exactly?

Comment: No it contains <u> element inside too. So maybe with a :contains or something like that it could scan the textarea on submit and return me what's inside all <u>.

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using, but on my Chrome and Firefox it renders `<ul>sd</ul>` as a text string inside of the textarea (which is the expected behavior I believe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit').on('click', function () {
        var val = $.trim( $('textarea').val() );
        var text = $('<div/>').html(val).find('u').text();
        // console.log(text);
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ewve8/1/

Update: You can use `map` method and join the returned array's elements:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
    var val = $.trim( $('textarea').val() ),
        text = $('<div/>').html(val).find('u').map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

    $('.res').html( text.join('<br>') ); 
})
```

Comment: Nice now with more <u> inside, how to return each <u> contents seperated with a <br> ?

Comment: Heh, I did an update in the meantime using almost the same methods http://jsfiddle.net/Ewve8/3/ +1 for the clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  For one thing, you aren't including the jQuery library in your fiddle.

Just load your textare content into a jQuery object and it will be parsed.  Then you can use `.filter('u')` to get the content you want:

```
var html = $($(this).val());
$('#res').html(html.filter('u').html());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QhsDY/

The one "gotcha" is that `.filter()` will only return top-level elements, so if the `<u>` is nested it won't work.  The fix is to use `.find()`, but the trick there is that `.find()` won't look at top-level elements.  So, wrap the contents in a `div` and then use `.find()`:

```
var html = $('<div/>').html($(this).val());
$('#res').html(html.find('u').html());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QhsDY/1/

As for multiple `<u>` elements, use `.each()`:

```
var html = $('<div/>').html($(this).val());

html.find('u').each(function() {
    $('#res').append($(this).html()+'<br>');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QhsDY/2/

Comment: Ok what's if they're more than 1 <u> inside the textarea ? And needed to be linebreak between each result

Comment: You would need to iterate over `.find()` results with `.each()`.  See edit.